# Iptables multiport and source ip

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a rule which does not seem to allow traffic as expected

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y --dports 38000:38100 -j ACCEPT
```

If I remove the -s  argument traffic seems to be allowed for this rule but if I add it again traffic is no longer allowed.

what is a little odd is that there is a rule above this one which works as expected, the only difference is that its not using -m multiport

```
-p tcp -m state --state NEW -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y --dport 38188 -j ACCEPT
```

the entire ruleset is as follows.

```
*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i !lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y --dport 38188 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -s x.x.x.x -d y.y.y.y -m multiport --dports 38000:38100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
```

The source and destination IP address are all correct so it must be something else I am missing, Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Can you add a LOG rule before the drops and retry, so we can say with confidence that iptables does not match?

Comment: -m state - deprecated. Use -m conntrack --ctstate new and show log dropped

Comment: Thanks for the help I have made both changes, from the log files I see that the source IP must be of the azure load balancer not sure why... So I have added an ACL to the Azure endpoint which will achieve the same I guess.